# Display Array values in Table using Ajax code.

Tags: html, ajax, laravel

Here is my code tried,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#doctorselected').on('change', function(e){
      console.log(e);
      var doctorid = e.target.value;
      var url = '{{URL::to('getdocDetails')}}';
      $.ajax({
         type : 'get',
         url  : url,
         data : {'doctorid':doctorid},
         success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
           var d = $.parseJSON(data);
           console.log(d);
            var output = '';
            $.each(d,function(i,e) {
                output += '<tr><td>'+e.products+'</td></tr>'
            });
            $('#tbody').append(output);
         },
         error:function(data)
         {
           console.log(data);
         }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

And here is the output for this code,

When I select the dropdown the all array values would be displayed, like example 
A,B,C,D

i Want to display the single value in each row

like this

```
A
B
C 
D
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you show us the content of `d`, i.e. what is the output of `console.log(d);`?

Comment: d - value 

[{…}]
0
:
{products: "Crocin,Sinarest"}
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array(0)

Comment: Data value is in JSON format but the length is 2,
["[{"products":"Sinarest", "Globate -G"}]"] 

I want want to process this and print Sinarent and Globate-G in the table

Answer (score 0):

The array you are sending as input to the `each` method has currently only one item, an object with the key `products` and the value with a comma separated list of products, in this case Crocin and Sinarest:

```
[{ 
    products: "Crocin,Sinarest" 
}]
```

As a result the list will only contain and show one item, this object.

You would need to convert the object to an array with the products in order to render a list. I would suggest to do this on the backend. You can do this with `explode(",", "Crocin,Sinarest");`

If you don't want to change the backend, you can do this in JavaScript as follows:

```
$.each(d[0].products.split(","), function (index, product) {
    output += '<tr><td>' + product + '</td></tr>'
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got the required output what i wanted to display.

As per your suggestions, 
I have used explode function to separate the comma. and here is the output,

     ["[{"products":"Sinarest", "Globate -G"}]"].

I just want to learn how to process this and print on the table. Can you please help me out?

And 2. You have used d[0] - May i know what is '0' th index? How is it splitting and displaying?

Comment: Try to apply the explode function on the products itself, then you will get a clean array with only the products as output. `0` is the index, because the example is an array with one object, you have to access that first. `.products` gives access to the key `products` in the object. With `split(",")` you can convert a string to an array, with the comma as separator. Play around with this, log the outputs and I'm sure you will find the solution. Try to only return the array with the products from your PHP code. Then you can just use `d` as input for the `each` function.

Comment: Yes. I will just play around parsing the data from the array instead of splitting in the view page. Thanks for taking a valuable time to explain me the things :)